# Access files on server

Tags: php, url, server

I have a private server on which I have placed a .php file in the root folder. 
I want to run the .php file script by accessing it from the URL.

SO how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you installed apache yet? to run a php page you need a web server like apache, nginx.

If installed, place your php file in `public_html` folder.
then, you can execute your php file by visiting `http://yourdomain.com/yourpage.php`